# get a list of the shortest path from one node to another on neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to find the **short way** between two nodes, getting a list of all the relations (with the properties) of the path.

If I have something like this:

```
MERGE (p1:Person{name: 'jim'})
MERGE (p2:Person{name: 'rob'})
MERGE (p3:Person{name: 'tom'})
MERGE (p4:Person{name: 'bob'})  

MERGE (p1)-[:FRIEND{age: '20'}]->(p2)
MERGE (p2)-[:NO_FRIEND{age: '35'}]->(p3)
MERGE (p3)-[:FRIEND{age: '20'}]->(p4)
MERGE (p2)-[:FOO{age: '40'}]->(p4)
```

Assuming that I need to go from `p1` to `p4`, the resulting list should be a list with:  *FRIEND{age: '20'} and FOO{age: '40'}*

If I need to go from `p1` to `p3`, the result should be *FRIEND{age: '20'} and NO_FRIEND{age: '35'}*

So I have this two requirements, the **short way**, and the **list with relationships**. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to use the `shortestPath` function and return the resulting path (which will give you the nodes and relationships along the path, along with their properties). For example, to get the shortest path from your `p1` to `p4` nodes:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((p1:Person {name: 'jim'})-[*]-(p4:Person {name: 'bob'}))
RETURN path;
```

You can use `allShortestPaths` function if you want to find all paths that have the same shortest path length.